# FluentUI DetailsList header drop down

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-fabric, fluent-ui

How to make FluentUI's DetailsList header show a drop down on click as in OneDrive?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZJyY.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/DetailsList/examples/DetailsList.Advanced.Example.tsx

Just show a ContextualMenu. Set its target to DetailsList's header row.